# allow button to respond to touch and not pass through to tableview when in a navigation controller or tabbar

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have a subclass of a `UIView` that loads its contents from a `xib`.  I take that view and insert it on the bottom of a `UIViewController` and it acts as a pop up menu - kind of like an action sheet.

Inside of the view I have the view, a header `UIImageView`, a background `UIImageView` and several buttons that effectively sit in front of the background image and they are connected to `IBActions` in the `UIView` subclass.

With a basic `UIViewController`, everything works great, no issues.  Using view animation it opens and closes and it you touch the buttons, they fire as expected.  I have this popping up in front of a `UITableView` and it works great.

The problem happens when I contain the `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController` or `UITabbarController`, when suddenly the buttons stop responding and any touches on the UIView start passing through to the tableview and select the tableview cell below it.

I've tried the following to "contain the touch".
 - set `exclusiveTouch` = YES on the background `UIView`, the image views the buttons, but it does not effect the touch.
 - verified `"user interaction"` disabled on the imageviews
 - tried using a custom button as the background of the `UIView` to capture the touch (as suggested in SO) but touches pass through that as well.
 - tried to override `hitTest` in the `UIView`, didn't work

- my buttons, and `tableview` are standard subclasses.

[image: view layout example]

Note: view size before and after animation
2013-04-17 07:20:03.975 FivePad[82813:c07] pop up will open

2013-04-17 07:20:03.975 FivePad[82813:c07] parent frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 411}}

2013-04-17 07:20:03.976 FivePad[82813:c07] menu frame before animation:{{0, 381}, {320, 51}}

2013-04-17 07:20:04.276 FivePad[82813:c07] pop up did open

2013-04-17 07:20:04.276 FivePad[82813:c07] menu frame after animation:{{0, 311}, {320, 51}}

Comment: Try checking the frame of your view -- usually this kind of problem with non-responsive buttons is because the buttons are outside the view's frame (but the view doesn't clip them, so they still appear).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  which frame should I check?  The buttons are inside of the UIView popup.  They are in the xib file and contained by the UIView which is then inserted as a subview of the view controller (superview)

Comment: Check the frame of the buttons' superview, the UIView popup after it's  opened.

Comment: Hi @rdelmar, thanks for helping.  Here are the view sizes before and after the animation: Note: added to original question for formatting.

Comment: Hi @redelmar.  your tip got me looking in the right direction.  I found I had "Autoresize Subviews" checked in storyboard scene for the view controller that was hosting the subview.  I believe that was the issue.